# Setting up an ifstream, getting 'error: expected initializer before ‘.’ token'

Tags: c++, debugging, std, ifstream

I received the following error in my compiler:

AccountDB.cpp: In member function ‘void AccountDB::processTransactions(const char*)’:
AccountDB.cpp:89:9: error: expected initializer before ‘.’ token
inFile2.open(transactFile);
         ^ (the carrot is over the period)

This is the relevant function. From similar errors on here, I suspect it has something to do with a namespace, but I'm not sure which. The function is supposed to read the date, account number and amount of a transaction and then process it using other nested functions.

```
void AccountDB::processTransactions(const char* transactFile)
{
//set up the input stream from the text file
ifstream inFile2;
//set up the variables to be read from text file
char date[6];
char type;
char accountnumber[20];
double amount, 

//open the file
inFile2.open(transactFile);
//standard check for file and exit if it doesn't exist
if(!inFile2)
{
    cout << "Error, input file could not be opened.\n";
    exit(1);
}
//Creates a header for listing transactions
cout << setw(5) << "Date"
     << setw(25) << "Account Number"
     << setw(5) << "Type"
     << setw(8) << "Amount"
     << setw(30) << "New Balance"
     << endl;
     inFile2 >> date;
     while (inFile2)
     {
        inFile2 >> accountnumber >> type >> amount;
        cout << setw(5) << date
             << setw(25) << accountnumber[20]
             << setw(5) << type
             << setw(8) << amount;
        int relevantAccount = searchForAccount(accountnumber);
        if (relevantAccount != -1)
        {
            if (type == 'P')
            {
                credArray[relevantAccount].processPayment(amount);
                cout << setw(30) << credArray[relevantAccount].getBalance() << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                bool chargestatus = credArray[relevantAccount].processCharge(amount);
                if (chargestatus = 1)
                    cout << setw(30) << credArray[relevantAccount].getBalance() << endl;
                else
                    cout << "Credit limit exceeded" << endl;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "Invalid account number" << endl;   
        inFile2 >> date;
    }
    cout << "End of transaction list." << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma after your variable declaration:

> ```
> double amount,
> //           ^
> ```

Change that to a semicolon `;`.